# Visual studio 2015 can't add Service Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, service-reference

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but none of them solved my problem.

I have a Windows Phone project, with some associated projects. I need to create a new project with the service reference, but I can't add it.

I found a link where they said to install a component from **Add Connected Service > find other services > WCF Services** but it says that my project is not supported.

Which kind of project must I create? I have in the same solution a project which has the **right-click > add service reference** but I was not the creator and I don't know what kind of project it is.

PS:
 - I **can't** right click > Add service reference, I tried it in both project name and reference name.
 - I need a Windows Phone Stuff. I link what i mean with a picture:
[image]
PSS: **The destination version of windows phone is not the reason. I tryed changing the WP8.0 into WP8.1 and I can still add the ref**

Does anyone know which kind of project I have to add for being able to add service ref?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Service Reference would suggest you to switch to the Windows recommended **REST API endpoints** instead. As now Windows is focusing more on REST service consumption than adding service reference that was available earlier.
Sadly now `Windows Phone Store` apps in `Windows Phone 8.1` do not support the `System.ServiceModel` namespace generated by the Add Service Reference menu. Hence they have removed the option `Add Service Reference`.
To be able to use it you will have to create a Silverlight application and use this [Workaround](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/myamama/2014/06/24/workaround-to-adding-service-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app/) of using a WCF service.
You can find a [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9ab43a4c-499a-4f2e-81e5-c1ab5acbe9bf/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=wpdevelop) discussion of the same.